# Why i cannot deploy my ear on Glassfish

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi

I have standard maven project in netbeans (netbeans' enterprise application), that have 1 war, 1 ejb and 1 ear modules. I want to inject with @Inject my @Stateless from ejb to war (REST class) using its interface. I have added some beans.xml files in correct folders in project, but im still getting this:

*Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [LogicBean] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private pl.edu.amu.wmi.kino.rk.rest.ReportRest.bean]. Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class pl.edu.amu.wmi.kino.rk.data.impl.LogicBeanImpl with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [LogicBean], Session bean [class pl.edu.amu.wmi.kino.rk.data.impl.LogicBeanImpl with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [LogicBean]]]. Please see server.log for more details.*

What am i doing wrong? I have searched the whole internet, but could not find the solution.
I know it is possible because i worked on a project with such a staff. THX for any help:)

Comment: post the pertinent code. trying to help with this kind of question is like fixing a watch wearing oven mitts.

Answer (score 1):

You're coding to the interface, which is good, but you have two implementations of that interface with the same qualifiers (the default ones in this case). Without using a qualifier to disambiguate what you want injected, CDI has no idea which one to give you.

I suggest creating a @Rest qualifier (or an EJB one) and annotating the class and also annotating the injection point with the instance you want.

Comment: i do not really know if i understand, but don't have 2 implementations of the interface, just one!

Comment: That's not what the error says. One is pl.edu.amu.wmi.kino.rk.data.impl.LogicBeanImpl and the other is also pl.edu.amu.wmi.kino.rk.data.impl.LogicBeanImpl. Somewhere that class is in there twice.

Comment: Oki, i am sorry, there are twice these beans (in ear/lib and war/lib), because of dependency to ejb in war. I just removed ear and deploy war finally.